# Flutter Web - http StreamedResponse as client to receive SSE

Tags: flutter, dart

Have a Flutter App that is able to receive SSE text/event-stream events when running on mobile but it is not receiving the same SSE text/event-stream events when running on the chrome web.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  http.Client _client;

  MyApp() : super() {
    print("Ctor called");
    subscribe();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("building..");
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter SSE',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Receive SSE Events'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Ready for events..'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  subscribe() async {
    print("Subscribing..");
    try {
      _client = http.Client();

      var request = new http.Request("GET", Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.11:8080/myserver/events"));
      request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
      request.headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";

      Future<http.StreamedResponse> response = _client.send(request);
      print("Subscribed!");

      response.asStream().listen((streamedResponse) {
        print("Received streamedResponse.statusCode:${streamedResponse.statusCode}");
        streamedResponse.stream.listen((data) {
          print("Received data:$data");
        });
      });
    } catch(e) {
      print("Caught $e");
    }
  }

  unsubscribe() {
    _client.close();
  }
}
```

On the server-side, I can see that the flutter app always subscribes okay as I can see the Sink being added. And the server-side always dispatches the events to the Sink but the flutter app only receives the events when running as a mobile app and NOT when running as a Chrome web app.

Is there a reason for this? Is this not the right approach to receive SSE events on a client flutter app that would run on a browser as well as a mobile app?

Flutter version is 1.10.6. Dart version is 2.5.1

---- Update ----

Did a flutter upgrade and now running with following:

```
Flutter 1.10.15-pre.79 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 72d5c1c805 (2 hours ago) • 2019-10-11 03:58:43 -0400
Engine • revision 8dabfb90a1
Tools • Dart 2.6.0 (build 2.6.0-dev.7.0 965b8cb1d8)
```

But still experiencing same behaviour in that streamed events can be received when running as mobile app but no streamed events can be received when running as Chrome web app.

--- Update 2 ---

I keep reading that there could be issues associated with CORS when running on a web browser but as far as I can see, there are no issues with CORS. CORS on the server-side has been configured to accept all origins (i.e. `"*"`), configured to accept `"GET"` and `"OPTIONS"` methods, and configured to accept all headers (i.e. `"*"`).

Debugging in Chrome browser shows that the response back is a 200 and can see the following response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
```

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the http protocol so I don't know if any of the response headers above should be reason for concern as to why an event stream cannot be received on a web browser?

As a side note, the flutter/dart code was originally written as angulardart/dart code and that code was able to receive streamed events fine when running on Chrome web browser (Therefore assuing that CORS was configured correctly).

Any help or pointers on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Even a simple "Yes" receiving streamed events is possible in current version of flutter web on Chrome so you must be doing something wrong on the server side. Or "No" this does not work in current version of flutter web on Chrome but eventually it will/never will, etc.

Comment: Did you get this solved? I'm having the same issue, just that the events are received when the SSE connection is closed (after Spring Boot default 30 seconds) on the server. Meaning suddenly I get hundreds of events, instead of as a stream. If you have the SSE connection timeout very high, you wouldn't notice the stream of events. Or, you simply have a completely different issue.

Comment: @apanloco Did you get this solved? ;) I'm also experiencing this issue - nothing is received until the connection is closed - then all of the hundreds of responses arrive at the same time. If I open the URL in a browser, the responses tick in every second, as expected.

Comment: I switched from SSE to websockets, and had more luck. I tried every SSE API, but they were all broken in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these issues are caused by blocked CORS, but the response looks fine on the logs you've shared. You can try running the web app with html renderer and see if this works. This usually solves connection issues, it's worth a try.

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

Streams on Flutter web seems to get dropped prematurely and it's tracked on this [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84252). You can also try switching to `dev` channel to see if it fixes the issue.